# Run program when booting into safe mode Win7

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, safe-mode

An attempt at security.

In an attempt to make my computer useless if stolen I have a batch file which tests for a file on my pen drive when booting and if not found then it switches to a dummy background and closes windows down. If my pen drive is present it takes a backup of my critical files and proceeds normally.

I would like to do the same when booting into safemode. I've found the Reg key that I think I needs but how to I tell it to run checkpen.bat ?

HKLM\SYstem\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot

Ian

Comment: I recommend looking into [truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) or [bitlocker drive encryption](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835565%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  That'll also make your computer useless if stolen (unless the thief formats the drive, which is just as much a danger with your USB dongle idea).  After all, what are the chances that the thief will acquire your USB flash drive at the same time as your computer?  Probably at least somewhat higher than his acquiring a decryption password.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do following

1.) Install the batch Job as a Service. The steps can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890)

2.) Make a entry in `HKLM\SYstem\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Minimal` with the name of the service. Add a default column and set it as `Service'

Hope this helps.

Comment: your page argues that you cant set a batch job as a service